# How can check the state (ON or OFF) of toggle button in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to validate the state of toggle button, whether it is ON or OFF?
I tried a lot but the one thing which is very strange is that, HTML is not getting changed in both the state.

```html
<div class="c-form-section">
<div class="o-grid">
<div class="o-grid__col o-grid__col--1-of-1">
<div class="o-grid__col o-grid__col--1-of-1 o-grid__col-tb--1-of-2"> </div>
<div class="o-grid__col o-grid__col--1-of-1 o-grid__col-tb--1-of-2 o-grid__col--spaced-tb">
<div class="u-spaced-top--quarter-square">
<section class="c-permission-fields">
<div class="c-permission-fields__block c-permission-fields__block--main ">
<div class="u-display--flex">
<div class="u-flex--grow">
<div>
<label class="c-control c-control--toggle ">
<input id="cardActivity" class="c-control__input" type="checkbox" value="1" name="cardActivity">
<span class="c-control__fake-input"></span>
<span class="c-control__label"> </span>
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

How m i suppose to validate this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your binding language Python, C#, Java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `is_selected()`(Python):

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("cardActivity")
if elem.is_selected():
    # do stuff if selected
```

`is_selected()` will check if checkbox is selected.

In Java would be like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("cardActivity"));
if (element.isSelected()){
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java binding:

```
boolean isChecked = driver.findElement(By.id("cardActivity")).isSelected();
```

or here is a method for checking/unchecking control:

```
public void checkCheckbox(boolean checked)
{
    WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.id("cardActivity"));
    if (checked != checkbox.isSelected())
    {
        checkbox.click();
    }
}
```

This code can be generalized for all controls of the same type but this is just general logic.

Comment: I simplified the logic in your function and changed the name of the parameter to `checked` to better indicate what it represents and what state means what.

Answer (score 0):

Dears follows a snippet using get_attribute("checked") method. Analyzing the attributes, it fits perfectly for what you want to do.

```
switch = instance.find_by_id(SWITCH_ID)

if switch.get_attribute("checked") == "false":
   # do something because the toggle button is unchecked
```