# Selenium cannot check if the toggle status is on or off (it always shows off)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a clickable toggle to turn it on / off. I am using Java Selenium to check the status (on/off) , then click it, and then check it again the status.

Based on the discussion in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650695/how-can-check-the-state-on-or-off-of-toggle-button-in-selenium) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650695/how-can-check-the-state-on-or-off-of-toggle-button-in-selenium) , I check the status using `isSelected()` but it doesn't seem to work properly.

This is the piece of HTML codes.

```html
<div formly-field="" ng-repeat="field in fields " ng-show="!field.hide" class="formly-field ng-scope ng-isolate-scope txtToggle topToggle formly-field-toggleSwitch" options="field" model="field.model || model" original-model="model" fields="fields" form="theFormlyForm"
  form-id="formly_35" form-state="options.formState" form-options="options" index="$index">
  <div class="form-group ng-scope" ng-class="{'has-error': showError}">
    <div class="col-xs-12 clearfix toggleRow">
      <div class="toggleWrapper switch-on" data-ng-class="{'switch-off': !model[options.key], 'switch-on': model[options.key]}">
        <div role="radio" class="toggle-switch ng-isolate-scope ng-valid" ng-class="{ 'disabled': disabled }" ng-model="model[options.key]" id="formly_2_toggleSwitch_AllowContactSMS_0" name="formly_2_toggleSwitch_AllowContactSMS_0" formly-custom-validation=""
          ng-click="options.templateOptions['onClick'](model[options.key], options, this, $event)" aria-describedby="formly_2_toggleSwitch_AllowContactSMS_0_description">
          <div class="toggle-switch-animate switch-on" ng-class="{'switch-off': !model, 'switch-on': model}"><span class="switch-left ng-binding" ng-bind="onLabel">On</span><span class="knob ng-binding" ng-bind="knobLabel"> </span><span class="switch-right ng-binding" ng-bind="offLabel">Off</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="switchLabel group" ng-class="to.subLabel ? 'group' : 'single'">
        <span class="switchTitle ng-binding">Toggle</span>
        <!-- ngIf: to.subLabel --><span ng-if="to.subLabel" class="switchSubTitle ng-binding ng-scope">alerts</span>
        <!-- end ngIf: to.subLabel -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ngIf: to.description -->
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how Selenium check it

```js
WebElement toggle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='formly_35']/child::div[1]//*[contains(@class,'toggle-switch-animate')]"));

boolean onOff = toggle.isSelected();

if (onOff.isSelected()) {
  log.debug("IS ON");
} else {
  log.debug("IS OFF");
}


toggle.click();


if (onOff.isSelected()) {
  log.debug("IS ON");
} else {
  log.debug("IS OFF");
}
```

I can see on the browser that the toggle is clicked and change the status from on to off or from off to on, but  Selenium always says `IS OFF`.

Can `isSelected` be used in this case to check if the toggle is on/off ? If not, what could be the workaround solution? Thanks.

Comment: isSelected is for inputs of type checkbox.  You'd want to check for "offLabel" or "onLabel" I think... (or class of 'switch-off' vs 'switch-on' ?)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking to check the attribute manually, but wondering if Selenium does have "out of the box" method to check the toggle status that Developer can use. Apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it to look if the class contains switch-on.

```
WebElement toggle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='formly_35']/child::div[1]//*[contains(@class,'toggle-switch-animate')]"));

boolean onOff = toggle.getAttribute("class").contains("switch-on");

if (onOff) {
  log.debug("IS ON");
} else {
  log.debug("IS OFF");
}


toggle.click();


if (onOff) {
  log.debug("IS ON");
} else {
  log.debug("IS OFF");
}
```

Comment: This manual method works. Unfortunately we need to check the attribute manually and `isSelected` cannot be used to check toggle status. Also no other ready to use Selenium method can be used.  Thanks for the answer.